# shared pointer holding a struct results in C2664 error

Tags: c++

I was trying out usage of shared pointers to hold structure pointers.

```
struct Person
{
    CString Name;

    struct Address
    {
        CString State;
        CString Country;
    };

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Address>> Addresses;
};

class PersonDB
{
    std::vector<Person*> m_People;
public:
    void AddPersonInfo(Person * Person_in)
    {
        m_People.push_back(Person_in);
    }
};
```

Why do I get this C2664 error?

```
auto main()->int
{
            Person * aPerson = new Person();
            auto aAddress = make_shared<Person::Address>(new Person::Address());

            aPerson->Addresses.push_back(std::move(aAddress));
            PersonDB * aPersonDB = new PersonDB();
            aPersonDB->AddPersonInfo(aPerson);
}
```

> error C2664: 'Person::Address::Address(const Person::Address &)' :
>   cannot convert argument 1 from 'Person::Address *' to 'const
>   Person::Address &'

Comment: Why do you need `std::move(aAddress)` here?

Comment: `make_shared<T>` doesn't take a pointer to `T` - it takes parameters that it forwards to `T`'s constructor. Make it `auto aAddress = make_shared<Person::Address>();`

Comment: What's with all the pointers and dynamic allocation?

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ - that was more to save the reference counter getting incremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the error is this line:

```
auto aAddress = make_shared<Person::Address>(new Person::Address());
```

`std::make_shared` actually allocates the object itself, forwarding the arguments to the objects constructor, resulting in something similar (not actually this code) to:

```
auto aAddress = std::shared_ptr<Person::Address>(
    new Person::Address(
        new Person::Address()
    ));
```

But Person::Address does not actually have a constructor to take a pointer like that, just a default constructor (no args) and a copy constructor (the const ref arg), resulting in that error. Thus you just wanted:

```
auto aAddress = std::maked_shared<Person::Address>();
```

Answer (score 1):

`make_shared`'s arguments are forwarded directly to the constructor of the type being constructed.

In your example:

```
auto aAddress = make_shared<Person::Address>(new Person::Address());
```

you are indicating that you wish to use `Person::Address`'s one-argument constructor, and the only one that exists is the copy constructor. This takes a `const Person::Address &` which is incompatible with the `Person::Address*` given to you by the expression `new Person::Address()`.

Drop the argument entirely to invoke the default constructor. This effectively does the `new` *for you*:

```
auto aAddress = make_shared<Person::Address>();
```

Comment: It did compile if the shared_ptr is assigned a pointer type. std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Address*>> Addresses; but yes that beats the purpose.

Comment: Don't see how; the template argument would be wrong.